# No puedo resolver este problema en mi plantilla de temas de Blogger con submenus

Tags: html, template, blogger

Hace poco instale una nueva plantilla en Blogger y he estado con un problema que no he sabido resolver. En los temas anteriores que utilicé, manejaba el tema de las páginas mediante la opción de diseño en Blogger y ahora en este tema se manejan mediante el codigo HTML. Mi problema esta en que necesito tener cuatro sub menus pero cuando agrego más de uno, aunque todos funcionen, no me permite seleccionar la primera opción del menu. Por ejemplo: En el menu tengo un orden como Contacto - Información - Submenú con enlaces. Entonces si yo quiero agregar otro submenú con enlaces, el botón de "Contacto" dejara de funcionar. Aunque en celular funcione correctamente, no logro hacerlo funcionar en la version de escritorio.

Este codigo que muestro aqui funciona

> `                    <b:section class='mnMen' id='header-Menu' maxwidgets='2' showaddelement='false'>
> <b:widget id='HTML000' locked='true' title='Navigation Menu' type='HTML' version='2' visible='true'>
> <b:widget-settings>
> <b:widget-setting name='content'>]]></b:widget-setting>
> </b:widget-settings>
> <b:includable id='main'>

```
                        <b:if cond='!data:view.isHomepage'>
                          <!--[ Home link ]-->
                          <li class='hm'>
                            <a class='a' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl.canonical' itemprop='url'>
                              <b:include name='home-icon'/>
                    
                              <!--[ Title navigation ]-->
                              <span class='n' itemprop='name'><data:messages.home/></span>
                            </a>
                          </li>
                        </b:if>
                
                        
                         <!--[ Standar menu ]-->
                        <li class='br'>
                          <!--[ Change attribute href='#' to add url ]-->
                          <a class='a' href='https://www.acf.com.ar' itemprop='url'>
                            <!--[ Icon ]-->
                            <b:include name='message-icon'/>
                      
                            <!--[ Title navigation ]-->
                            <span class='n' itemprop='name'>Inicio</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        
                         <!--[ Standar menu ]-->
                        <li class='br'>
                          <!--[ Change attribute href='#' to add url ]-->
                          <a class='a' href='https://www.acf.com.ar/p/contacto_29.html' itemprop='url'>
                            <!--[ Icon ]-->
                            <b:include name='message-icon'/>
                      
                            <!--[ Title navigation ]-->
                            <span class='n' itemprop='name'>Contacto</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        
                         <!--[ Standar menu ]-->
                        <li class='br'>
                          <!--[ Change attribute href='#' to add url ]-->
                          <a class='a' href='https://www.acf.com.ar/p/publicidad.html' itemprop='url'>
                            <!--[ Icon ]-->
                            <b:include name='message-icon'/>
                      
                            <!--[ Title navigation ]-->
                            <span class='n' itemprop='name'>Publicidad</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        
                           <!--[ Standar menu ]-->
                        <li class='br'>
                          <!--[ Change attribute href='#' to add url ]-->
                          <a class='a' href='https://www.acf.com.ar/p/portfolio.html' itemprop='url'>
                            <!--[ Icon ]-->
                            <b:include name='message-icon'/>
                      
                            <!--[ Title navigation ]-->
                            <span class='n' itemprop='name'>Trabajos</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <!--[ Standar menu ]-->
                        <li class='br'>
                          <!--[ Change attribute href='#' to add url ]-->
                          <a class='a' href='https://www.acf.com.ar/p/menciones.html' itemprop='url'>
                            <!--[ Icon ]-->
                            <b:include name='message-icon'/>
                      
                            <!--[ Title navigation ]-->
                            <span class='n' itemprop='name'>Menciones</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <!--[ Standar menu ]-->
                        <li class='br'>
                          <!--[ Change attribute href='#' to add url ]-->
                          <a class='a' href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/Prensa' itemprop='url'>
                            <!--[ Icon ]-->
                            <b:include name='message-icon'/>
                      
                            <!--[ Title navigation ]-->
                            <span class='n' itemprop='name'>Prensa</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        
                     
                
                        <!--[ Dropdown style 1 ]-->
                        <li class='drp'>
                          <input class='drpI hidden' id='drpDwn-1' name='drpDwn' type='checkbox'/>
                          <label class='a' for='drpDwn-1'>
                            <!--[ Icon ]-->
                            <b:include name='folder-icon'/>
                      
                            <!--[ Title navigation ]-->
                            <span class='n'>Eventos</span>
                    
                            <b:include name='arow-down-icon'/>
                          </label>
                          <ul>
                            <!--[ Change attribute href='#' to add url ]-->
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/Carnaval%202023' itemprop='url'>Carnaval del Sol 2023</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/CDSD2024' itemprop='url'>Carnaval del Sol 2024</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/FDLG2023' itemprop='url'>Fiesta de la Guitarra 2023</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/FDLG2024' itemprop='url'>Fiesta de la Guitarra 2024</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/Fiesta%20de%20Las%20Termas' itemprop='url'>Fiesta Termas de Dolores 2022</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/FDLTA%202023' itemprop='url'>Fiesta de la Torta Argentina 2023</a></li>
                                                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        
                      
                      </ul>
                    </b:includable>
                  </b:widget>
                  <b:widget id='PageList000' locked='false' title='ACF (Simple)' type='PageList' version='2' visible='false'>
                    <b:widget-settings>
                      <b:widget-setting name='pageListJson'><![CDATA[{"link1":{"href":"#","position":1,"title":"About"},"link0":{"href":"/","position":0,"title":"Home"},"link3":{"href":"#","position":3,"title":"Custom menu"},"link2":{"href":"#","position":2,"title":"Contact"}}]]></b:widget-setting>
                      <b:widget-setting name='homeTitle'>Página Principal</b:widget-setting>
                    </b:widget-settings>
                    <b:includable id='main'>
                      <b:include name='content'/>
                    </b:includable>
                    <b:includable id='content'>
                      <b:include name='pageList'/>
                    </b:includable>
                    <b:includable id='overflowButton'/>
                    <b:includable id='overflowablePageList'/>
                    <b:includable id='pageLink'>
                      <b:if cond='data:i &lt;= 4'>
                        <li>
                          <b:class cond='data:link.isCurrentPage' name='selected'/>
                          <b:class cond='data:link.href == data:blog.homepageUrl.canonical' name='hm'/>
                    
                          <b:tag class='a' expr:name='!data:link.isCurrentPage and data:link.href != &quot;#&quot; ? &quot;a&quot; : &quot;span&quot;'>
                            <b:attr cond='!data:link.isCurrentPage and data:link.href != &quot;#&quot;' expr:value='data:link.href' name='href'/>
                            <b:attr cond='!data:link.isCurrentPage and data:link.href != &quot;#&quot;' name='itemprop' value='url'/>`
```

Pero este codigo no:

```
                    <b:section class='mnMen' id='header-Menu' maxwidgets='2' showaddelement='false'>
                  <b:widget id='HTML000' locked='true' title='Navigation Menu' type='HTML' version='2' visible='true'>
                    <b:widget-settings>
                      <b:widget-setting name='content'><![CDATA[<!--[ you can only edit this widget from HTML theme ]-->]]></b:widget-setting>
                    </b:widget-settings>
                    <b:includable id='main'>
                      <ul class='mnMn' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='https://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement'>
              
                        <b:if cond='!data:view.isHomepage'>
                          <!--[ Home link ]-->
                          <li class='hm'>
                            <a class='a' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl.canonical' itemprop='url'>
                              <b:include name='home-icon'/>
                    
                              <!--[ Title navigation ]-->
                              <span class='n' itemprop='name'><data:messages.home/></span>
                            </a>
                          </li>
                        </b:if>
                
                        
                         <!--[ Standar menu ]-->
                        <li class='br'>
                          <!--[ Change attribute href='#' to add url ]-->
                          <a class='a' href='https://www.acf.com.ar' itemprop='url'>
                            <!--[ Icon ]-->
                            <b:include name='message-icon'/>
                      
                            <!--[ Title navigation ]-->
                            <span class='n' itemprop='name'>Inicio</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        
                         <!--[ Standar menu ]-->
                        <li class='br'>
                          <!--[ Change attribute href='#' to add url ]-->
                          <a class='a' href='https://www.acf.com.ar/p/contacto_29.html' itemprop='url'>
                            <!--[ Icon ]-->
                            <b:include name='message-icon'/>
                      
                            <!--[ Title navigation ]-->
                            <span class='n' itemprop='name'>Contacto</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        
                         <!--[ Standar menu ]-->
                        <li class='br'>
                          <!--[ Change attribute href='#' to add url ]-->
                          <a class='a' href='https://www.acf.com.ar/p/publicidad.html' itemprop='url'>
                            <!--[ Icon ]-->
                            <b:include name='message-icon'/>
                      
                            <!--[ Title navigation ]-->
                            <span class='n' itemprop='name'>Publicidad</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        
                           <!--[ Standar menu ]-->
                        <li class='br'>
                          <!--[ Change attribute href='#' to add url ]-->
                          <a class='a' href='https://www.acf.com.ar/p/portfolio.html' itemprop='url'>
                            <!--[ Icon ]-->
                            <b:include name='message-icon'/>
                      
                            <!--[ Title navigation ]-->
                            <span class='n' itemprop='name'>Trabajos</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <!--[ Standar menu ]-->
                        <li class='br'>
                          <!--[ Change attribute href='#' to add url ]-->
                          <a class='a' href='https://www.acf.com.ar/p/menciones.html' itemprop='url'>
                            <!--[ Icon ]-->
                            <b:include name='message-icon'/>
                      
                            <!--[ Title navigation ]-->
                            <span class='n' itemprop='name'>Menciones</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <!--[ Standar menu ]-->
                        <li class='br'>
                          <!--[ Change attribute href='#' to add url ]-->
                          <a class='a' href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/Prensa' itemprop='url'>
                            <!--[ Icon ]-->
                            <b:include name='message-icon'/>
                      
                            <!--[ Title navigation ]-->
                            <span class='n' itemprop='name'>Prensa</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        
                     
                
                        <!--[ Dropdown style 1 ]-->
                        <li class='drp'>
                          <input class='drpI hidden' id='drpDwn-1' name='drpDwn' type='checkbox'/>
                          <label class='a' for='drpDwn-1'>
                            <!--[ Icon ]-->
                            <b:include name='folder-icon'/>
                      
                            <!--[ Title navigation ]-->
                            <span class='n'>Eventos</span>
                    
                            <b:include name='arow-down-icon'/>
                          </label>
                          <ul>
                            <!--[ Change attribute href='#' to add url ]-->
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/Carnaval%202023' itemprop='url'>Carnaval del Sol 2023</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/CDSD2024' itemprop='url'>Carnaval del Sol 2024</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/FDLG2023' itemprop='url'>Fiesta de la Guitarra 2023</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/FDLG2024' itemprop='url'>Fiesta de la Guitarra 2024</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/Fiesta%20de%20Las%20Termas' itemprop='url'>Fiesta Termas de Dolores 2022</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/FDLTA%202023' itemprop='url'>Fiesta de la Torta Argentina 2023</a></li>
                                                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        
                        <!--[ Dropdown style 1 ]-->
                        <li class='drp'>
                          <input class='drpI hidden' id='drpDwn-2' name='drpDwn' type='checkbox'/>
                          <label class='a' for='drpDwn-2'>
                            <!--[ Icon ]-->
                            <b:include name='folder-icon'/>
                      
                            <!--[ Title navigation ]-->
                            <span class='n'>Fútbol</span>
                    
                            <b:include name='arow-down-icon'/>
                          </label>
                          <ul>
                            <!--[ Change attribute href='#' to add url ]-->
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/1ra%20Mas' itemprop='url'>Primera división masculina</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/1ra%20Fem' itemprop='url'>Primera división femenina</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/Reserva' itemprop='url'>Reserva</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/4ta%20Divisi%C3%B3n' itemprop='url'>Cuarta división</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/5ta%20Divisi%C3%B3n' itemprop='url'>Quinta división</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/6ta%20Divisi%C3%B3n' itemprop='url'>Sexta División</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/Infantiles' itemprop='url'>Infantiles</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/LIDFDD' itemprop='url'>Liga Independiente de Dolores</a></li>
                            <li itemprop='name'><a href='https://www.acf.com.ar/search/label/TNDF' itemprop='url'>Torneos Nocturnos de Fútbol</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>

                      </ul>
                    </b:includable>
                  </b:widget>
                  <b:widget id='PageList000' locked='false' title='ACF (Simple)' type='PageList' version='2' visible='false'>
                    <b:widget-settings>
                      <b:widget-setting name='pageListJson'><![CDATA[{"link1":{"href":"#","position":1,"title":"About"},"link0":{"href":"/","position":0,"title":"Home"},"link3":{"href":"#","position":3,"title":"Custom menu"},"link2":{"href":"#","position":2,"title":"Contact"}}]]></b:widget-setting>
                      <b:widget-setting name='homeTitle'>Página Principal</b:widget-setting>
                    </b:widget-settings>
                    <b:includable id='main'>
                      <b:include name='content'/>
                    </b:includable>
                    <b:includable id='content'>
                      <b:include name='pageList'/>
                    </b:includable>
                    <b:includable id='overflowButton'/>
                    <b:includable id='overflowablePageList'/>
                    <b:includable id='pageLink'>
                      <b:if cond='data:i &lt;= 4'>
                        <li>
                          <b:class cond='data:link.isCurrentPage' name='selected'/>
                          <b:class cond='data:link.href == data:blog.homepageUrl.canonical' name='hm'/>
                    
                          <b:tag class='a' expr:name='!data:link.isCurrentPage and data:link.href != &quot;#&quot; ? &quot;a&quot; : &quot;span&quot;'>
                            <b:attr cond='!data:link.isCurrentPage and data:link.href != &quot;#&quot;' expr:value='data:link.href' name='href'/>
                            <b:attr cond='!data:link.isCurrentPage and data:link.href != &quot;#&quot;' name='itemprop' value='url'/>
```